# Convert from FAT(little endian) to Big-endian

Tags: fat32

How to Convert the following sequence from little to big-endian: 5E 8D 70 6D. And please explain how to calculate it.

Comment: Do you know the definition of "little endian" and "big endian"? That would be a good place to start researching.

Comment: https://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-15/ass15_3.html

Comment: OK, given you understand the definitions of little endian and big endian, and you know the byte sequence you've posted is little endian, what would the big endian equivalent be?